# confusion about variable scope in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Consider the following code which is taken from 
https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/#building-a-temperature-converter-example-app:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Temperature Converter")

frm_entry = tk.Frame(master=window)
ent_temperature = tk.Entry(master=frm_entry, width=10)
lbl_temp = tk.Label(master=frm_entry, text="\N{DEGREE FAHRENHEIT}")

ent_temperature.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
lbl_temp.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

btn_convert = tk.Button(
    master=window,
    text="\N{RIGHTWARDS BLACK ARROW}",
    command=fahrenheit_to_celsius  # <--- Add this line
)

...

def fahrenheit_to_celsius():
    """Convert the value for Fahrenheit to Celsius and insert the
    result into lbl_result.
    """
    fahrenheit = ent_temperature.get()
    celsius = (5/9) * (float(fahrenheit) - 32)
    lbl_result["text"] = f"{round(celsius, 2)} \N{DEGREE CELSIUS}"
```

I am wondering how fahrenheit_to_celsius is able to access ent_temperature since it is defined out of scope of the function is it not?

Thanks!

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, variables that are only referenced outside a function are global variables.

Now, ent_temperature is a global variable which means that all functions can read from it, without the need of defying it inside the function.

Quoting w3schools:

> A variable created in the main body of the Python code is a global variable and belongs to the global scope.
>   Global variables are available from within any scope, global and local.

Comment: thanks, I thought one always has to use the keyword "global" for defining global variables

Comment: @peterparker ***all functions have access to it***: This gives only **read only** permission.

Comment: @stovfl , I jut edited my answer. You could edit my answer instead of down voting i guess